# VBA code to drag row down to a specific row that is displayed

Tags: excel, vba

[After macro runs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gXFC.png)

[Before macro runs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbskN.png)

Hi, I'm trying to write VBA code for the table shown in the image which is a multiplication table. I know how to use for loops if it was simply to use cell referencing and multiplication in the for loop but I'm trying to work directly from what I have so far because that is required from me in my homework. My VBA code is below

```
    Sub Macro1()

    Range("C5:F5").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C5:F9"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("C5:F9").Select

    Range("B5", Range("B4").End(xlDown)).ClearContents

    For rw = 1 To Range("B2").Value

    Cells(rw + 4, 2) = rw

    Next rw

End Sub
```

My for loop calculates the row number dependent on the number in cell B2 and I have the code so far to copy the 4 columns C to F where the formula for multiplication is and drag it down to a random row. But what I need is for the code to allow the copying of the 4 cells to paste into the last row displayed in column B. For instance if the number of rows was 10 all the cells in between the columns would fill up but as you can see in the image it hasn't. Also, please note I am trying to keep the column fixed so I don't need code that displays different number of columns. I just need to copy and paste the formulas in the first rows to the last row number which is dependent on the number in B2

I know the simple for loop for multiplication is

```
Sub Macro1()

Range("B4:FF4000").ClearContents

For rw = 1 To Range("B2").Value
    For colctr = 1 To Range("B3").Value
        Cells(rw + 4, colctr + 1) = rw * colctr
    Next colctr
Next rw

End Sub
```

But I need to use the copy and paste in the macro and for it to end on the value of rows in cell B2.